# Why "Avira System Tray Tool (avgnt.exe)" is using very high commited memory?

Tags: memory, commit, avira

My "Avira System Tray Tool" using very high memory after minutes of system Log in.

Below pic is show how many vast memory it uses:

[image: 1]

More than 1900 MB!

Is my System Infected?!

Is this caused due to an incompatibility with Norton Internet Security?

Is there anyone else having same problem?

Comment: well I definitly wouldnt use Norton with Avira. Norton has all kinds of compatibility issues with programs like that

Comment: I`m use avira just for it`s firewall "transfer" feature and it`s clear manual rules. (all other components are not installed)